# Stack space overflow error in Haskell with a very small stack size

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

The Haskell program

```
main=main>>main
```

fails with

```
2mem: Stack space overflow: current size 33624 bytes.
2mem: Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

33k seems quite small. The OS (via top) is reporting a total memory usage of 6G before failing. When I compile the program with `ghc -rtsopts 2mem.hs` and run it with `./2mem +RTS -K32M` I sill get the same error.

I'm using ghc, version 8.0.1 on MacOS 10.11.6.

Why is the stack space so small and why doesn't `-K32M` increase it?

Comment: It hardly matters. Your program will blow the stack no matter how you run it. It's basically the same as `main = main`, but the later will produce a `<<loop>>` exception instead of a stack overflow. 33K is a pretty large stack for the way GHC uses it.

Comment: The reported stack size in the message is wrong. I thought this got fixed though.

Comment: @ReidBarton: a bug in ghc, maybe [this one](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10445), although it is marked as "fixed"? Anyone familiar with the ghc bug tracking system? Is there a way to re-open a ticket?

Comment: Yes that's the one I was thinking of. I reopened the ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in GHC; the reported stack size in the message is wrong. See https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10445 and thanks for noticing that it's not actually fixed.